# Filter out subclasses from superclasses array

Tags: swift

I want an array of subclasses from a superclasses array. See my code example:

```
class A {}
class B: A {}

let arr: [A] = [A(), B()]

let arrOfBs: [B] = arr.filter { $0 as B } // Error here
```

How can I correctly filter out all the Bees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [compactMap](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap):

```
let arrOfBs = arr.compactMap { $0 as? B }
```

(or [flatMap](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2907182-flatmap) for Swift < 4.1)

Technically you could also use:

```
let arrOfBs = arr.filter { $0 is B } as! [B]
```

but `compactMap` is simpler and without nasty force-casts.

Comment: Thank you, will accept it in 10 minutes. I thought I could only use filter to filter out the options.

Comment: @J.Doe `compactMap` is a combination of `filter` and `map` and usually you would use it to filter out `nil` values. This is only one common application.

Comment: The former approach also has the benefit of doing one pass through the array. The latter does 2 passes.

Answer (score 0):

You are filter a data type that can be used `is`  not  `as`

```
    class A {}
    class B: A {}

    let arr: [A] = [A(), B()]

    let arrOfBs = arr.filter { $0 is B } as? [B]
    print(arrOfBs?.count)
```

> Note This result optional you can use `if let` or `guard`

Comment: The result can't be `nil` though because of the `filter` condition. Why not use `as!` then?

Comment: @Sulthan filter result type Bool You cannot use the casting type , this code arr.filter { $0 as B } compiler error Cannot convert value of type 'B' to closure result type 'Bool'